# Open Office Calc - Round to 5?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

Is there a way I can have a cell round a number to the the nearest 5?
For example, the number 114 would round to 115, or 62 would round to 60

Answer (score 9):

Use the following formula (example for A1):

```
=MROUND(A1; 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

@Lance Roberts answer picks up on the built in formula for this... but you can also "cheat" your way there as well:

```
=round(A1/5; 0)*5
```

In other words, divide the target by 5, round to the nearest whole number, and then multiply by 5.

For your examples, this does:

- 114/5 = 22.8 -> 23 * 5 = 115
- 62/5 = 12.4 -> 12 * 5 = 60